# How to execute 2 functions at the same time when updating the UI

Tags: ios, swift, multithreading, in-app-purchase

I'm implementing `In App purchases` which work quite well. I'm implementing both `Auto-Renewable` and `Non-renewable` subscriptions. I can determine when either subscription is active and expired as well. I can update the user Profile UI according the status of subscription but can only do it when i check one at a time.

If i call both `functions` when the view is about to appear. The UI gets messed up and doesn't display the correct status. I have debugged and seen that if first one checks one subscription, updates its status, when i move out of the `view` and come back it checks the other goes back to the default status which is `standard account` because `Auto-renewable` is expired. Is there a way i run both functions at the same time and also use them to update my UI at the same time. Below is my code.

```
var isUserActive: Bool?

var user: User {
    return AppDelegate.shared.user
}

func setUserAccountType() {
    if self.isUserActive == nil {
        self.userAccountType.text = ""
        self.userGoGold.isHidden = true
    } else {
        if self.isUserActive! {
            self.userAccountType.text = "Gold Account"
        } else {
            self.userAccountType.text = "Standard Account"
            self.userGoGold.isHidden = false
        }
    }
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.setUserAccountType()
    IAPManager.shared.getProducts()
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ pAnimated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(pAnimated)
    self.checkForAutoRenewableSubscription()
    self.checkForNonRenewableSubscription()
}

func setUpUserAccountStatus(_ pIsActive: Bool) {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.isUserActive = pIsActive
        self.setUserAccountType()
        self.reloadRowForIdentifier(.billing)
        self.activityIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = true
        self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
    }
}

func checkForAutoRenewableSubscription() {
    self.activityIndicator.startAnimating()
    self.user.checkIfSubscriptionIsActive { (pIsActive) in
        self.setUpUserAccountStatus(pIsActive)
    }
}

func checkForNonRenewableSubscription() {
    self.activityIndicator.startAnimating()
    self.user.checkifNonRenewableSubscriptionIsActive { (pSubscribed) in
        self.setUpUserAccountStatus(pSubscribed)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `DispatchGroup` and inside it's notify part do what you need

```
let dispatchGroup = DispatchGroup()
var inpIsActive = false
var inpSubscribed = false

func checkForAutoRenewableSubscription() {
    dispatchGroup.enter()
    self.activityIndicator.startAnimating()
    self.user.checkIfSubscriptionIsActive { (pIsActive) in
        self.inpIsActive = pIsActive   
        self.dispatchGroup.leave()
    }
}

func checkForNonRenewableSubscription() {
    dispatchGroup.enter()
    self.activityIndicator.startAnimating()
    self.user.checkifNonRenewableSubscriptionIsActive { (pSubscribed) in
        self.inpSubscribed = pSubscribed  
        self.dispatchGroup.leave()
    }
}
```

And inside `viewDidLoad`

```
checkForAutoRenewableSubscription()
checkForNonRenewableSubscription() 
dispatchGroup.notify(queue: .main) { 
   self.setUpUserAccountStatus()
}
```

Comment: And where do you run `dispatchGroup.notify(queue: .main)`. `ViewwillAppear` or?

Comment: `self.setUpUserAccountStatus(pIsActive: Bool)` has a `Bool` parameter. did you get rid of it?. Coz when it asks for one?

Comment: remove it from function , now you have 2 bool values for your subscriptions

Comment: Prints out the message `Both functions are complete` but UI doesn't appear at all now. All blank now

Comment: inside `setUpUserAccountStatus` use the 2 added bool values in answer to configure it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190510/discussion-between-sk123-and-sh-khan).